# didDiscoverPeripheral not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to scan for advertising peripherals I have a few out that are advertising for testing purposes.

I have my core bluetooth methods in a singleton file as a manager for the app

This is in my `.h`

```
@interface MyBluetoothManager : NSObject <CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>
```

And these methods are in my `.m`

```
+ (MyBluetoothManager *)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    __strong static AGBluetoothManager *_sharedObject = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return _sharedObject;
}
- (id)init { 
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.cbCentralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];            
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)startScan {
    if (self.isBluetoothPowerOn) {
        if (!self.isCBReady) {
            [self printLog:@"Scanning for devices..."];
            [self.cbCentralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Bluetooth NOT on, turn on bluetooth from settings");
    }
}

- (void)centralmanager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {

    NSLog(@"Did discover peripheral. peripheral: %@ rssi: %@, UUID: %@ advertisementData: %@ ", peripheral, RSSI, peripheral.identifier, advertisementData);
    //....
    //...
}
```

I have IBOutlet action in another class that when I tap it fires `startScan`

```
[MyBluetoothManager sharedInstance] startScan];
```

then I get these messages in the debugger `CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready` then `scanning for devices...` but nothing else I have a breakpoint inside `didDiscoverPeripheral` but it never gets fired. Any idea on what could be going wrong? I have all the necessary set up and delegates

Comment: Does the Light Blue app from the App Store discover the peripherals?

Comment: @Paulw11 oddly not, it's just discovering my mac, apple watch and iPhone. Not the peripheral that i'm interested in scanning. However the app is not even discovering those. I can however see the peripheral i'm interested in when I go to the Bluetooth menu in Settings

Comment: Core Bluetooth will only discover BLE devices if your peripheral appears in Bluetooth settings it is probably a legacy Bluetooth device, not a BLE device. What is it?